# How do I programmatically set the new tab page in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So by default, the new tab page is replaced with my Chrome extension (via the manifest). However, I'd like to give the option to disable it (programmatically).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google made a Star Wars new tab replacement which allows you to view the default new tab page. The url it uses is chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html. Example:

options.html:

```
<input type="checkbox"> Use default new tab page
```

options.js:

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]")
checkbox.addEventListener("click", function() {
 chrome.storage.sync.set({ defaultnewtab: checkbox.checked })
})
```

newtab.js:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("defaultnewtab", function(storage) {
 if(storage.defaultnewtab) {
  chrome.tabs.update({ url: "chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html" })
} })
```

Comment: This won't work always. The extension should show the last set new tab page instead of the Chrome's default one.